# Phonegap iOS push notifications not received

Tags: php, ios, cordova, push-notification

We manage a push notifications for both platforms iOS and Android. The procedure for Android is well, the device has been registered to GCM and the notifications are received. The problem is with APNS for iOS, the notifications are not received! even the device had been registered correctly and APNS generated a token for the device.

Below are the Javascript for receiving push and PHP code for sending messages.

**Javascript code for receiving push:**

```
var pushNotification;
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReadyEvent, false);

function onDeviceReadyEvent(){
pushNotification = window.plugins.pushNotification;

var sk_deviceplatform = device.platform;
sk_deviceplatform = sk_deviceplatform.toLowerCase();

if(sk_deviceplatform === 'android'){
pushNotification.register(successHandler, errorHandler, {"senderID":"XXXXXXXXX","ecb":"onNotificationGCM"});
} else {
pushNotification.register(tokenHandler, errorHandler, {"badge":"true","sound":"true","alert":"true","ecb":"onNotificationAPN"});
}
}

function tokenHandler(result) {
    console.log("Token: " + result);
    alert("Token: "+ result);
}

function errorHandler(error) {
    console.log("Error: " + error); 
    alert('Error:' + error);
}

    function onNotificationAPNS(e){
    if(e.alert.title) {
    $.mobile.changePage( "handle_notifications.html?id="+e.eventid, { transition: "slide"} );
    }
    if(e.sound) {
    var skpn_snd = new Media(e.sound);
    skpn_snd.play();
    }
    if (e.badge) {
    pushNotification.setApplicationIconBadgeNumber(successHandler, errorHandler, e.badge);
    }
    if (e.foreground===0){
    // when application is not active
          }else{
    navigator.notification.alert(e.alert.title, null, 'News Notification', 'OK');          
          }
}
```

**PHP code for sending push:**

```
/*** PUSH NOTIFICATION FOR IOS VIA APNS ***/

set_time_limit(0);
// charset header for output
header('content-type: text/html; charset: utf-8');
   $deviceIds = array(/* get all devices token ids from the database */);
if(count($deviceIds)>0){
// this is where you can customize your notification

$body['aps'] = array(
    'badge' => +1,
    'alert' => "News Event!",
    'sound' => 'default'
);

$payload = json_encode($body);
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// start to create connection
$ctx = stream_context_create();
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'local_cert', "XXXX.pem");
stream_context_set_option($ctx, 'ssl', 'passphrase', "XXXXXXX");
foreach ($deviceIds as $item_device) {    
// Open a connection to the APNS server
$fp = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT | STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $ctx);
if(!$fp){ exit("Failed to connect: $err $errstr" . '<br />');}else{/* service online */}
// Build the binary notification
$msg_notification = chr(0) . pack('n', 32) . pack('H*', $item_device) . pack('n', strlen($payload)) . $payload;     
// Send it to the server
$result = fwrite($fp, $msg_notification, strlen($msg_notification));     
if (!$result) { echo 'Undelivered message count: ' . $item_device . '<br />';}
else { /* notifications are sent */ }
if ($fp){
     ## check for errors
     $apple_error_response = fread($fp, 6); //byte1=always 8, byte2=StatusCode, bytes3,4,5,6=identifier(rowID). Should return nothing if OK.
       //NOTE: Make sure you set stream_set_blocking($fp, 0) or else fread will pause your script and wait forever when there is no response to be sent.
       if ($apple_error_response) {
            $error_response = unpack('Ccommand/Cstatus_code/Nidentifier', $apple_error_response); //unpack the error response (first byte 'command" should always be 8)
            if ($error_response['status_code'] == '0') {
                $error_response['status_code'] = '0-No errors encountered';

            } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '1') {
                $error_response['status_code'] = '1-Processing error';

            } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '2') {
                $error_response['status_code'] = '2-Missing device token';

            } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '3') {
                $error_response['status_code'] = '3-Missing topic';

            } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '4') {
                $error_response['status_code'] = '4-Missing payload';

            } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '5') {
                $error_response['status_code'] = '5-Invalid token size';

            } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '6') {
                $error_response['status_code'] = '6-Invalid topic size';

            } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '7') {
                $error_response['status_code'] = '7-Invalid payload size';

            } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '8') {
                $error_response['status_code'] = '8-Invalid token';

            } else if ($error_response['status_code'] == '255') {
                $error_response['status_code'] = '255-None (unknown)';

            } else {
                $error_response['status_code'] = $error_response['status_code'].'-Not listed';
            }
            echo '<br><b>ERROR</b> Response Command:<b>' . $error_response['command'] . '</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Identifier:<b>' . $error_response['identifier'] . '</b>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Status:<b>' . $error_response['status_code'] . '</b><br>';
            echo 'Identifier is the rowID (index) in the database that caused the problem, and Apple will disconnect you from server. To continue sending Push Notifications, just start at the next rowID after this Identifier.<br>';
       }

fclose($fp);
$_ENV['connection_status'] = 'The connection has been closed by the client' . '<br />';
}
} 
set_time_limit(30);
}
```

When we send a message, there is no errors and every think is well, but the push notifications are not received.
The problem is either inside the PHP script or with the apache cordova script...

Thank you for your suggestions...

Comment: you need to come out of the app totally to receive a push

Comment: And if i'm inside the application?? how proceed to do an alert?

Comment: The onNotificationAPNS procedure had never been fired!

Comment: have you received the push notification when you are out of the app? if so, when you are in the app catch the notification in this method "- (void)application:(UIApplication*)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary*)userInfo" and then show the notification in alertview.

Comment: The push notifications are never fired and not received, even the php code had not returned any error!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had found the problem...We tried to send push via APNS with development certificate using the production connection server.
For production, use the connection below:

```
ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195
```

For development, use the connection below:

```
ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to install these two cordova plugins.

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device

https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-console

Because these two, you can't detect your `device type` and `console` your output.

Comment: Kindly; these two cordova plugins had already installed and set up from the config.xml file, and the problem is not from that, because the push are received on Android. The problem is on iOS.